Double-slit experiment with Buckyballs
Is it true that in the double-slit experiment with Buckyballs, performed in 1999 at the University of Vienna by Anton Zeilinger, a crystal (which scatters the launched molecules) was used instead of a real traditional physical grate (multiple slits at which the molecules are aimed)?

See the paper:
Wave-Particle Duality of C60 Molecules
Arndt et al, 1999
According to this, they used a grating with 100nm separated diffraction slits and 50nm widths composed of Silicon Nitride (actually just specifies SiNx).
Pretty slick experiment! So no, they used a diffraction grating and not a crystal.
You might want to check out this paper from most of the same team in 2001.  They discuss alternative techniques to diffraction other than traditional grating for large molecules such as C60.
Diffraction of complex molecules by structures made of light
